# How to pass argv[1] from main into a function?

Tags: c, function, cs50, argv

How do I take `argv[1]` from `main` so that I can use it in my function called `only_digits`? You don't have to show it to me on my code. I would just like to see, how `argv[1]` (that is stored in `main`) can be used in a function (outside of `main`).

It is also the first time I've used a bool function. I'm wondering if, in the `<cs50.h>` library, you can use strings and bools the way I used them here. Am I using them right?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool only_digits(string);

int x;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string s = argv[1];
    x = only_digits(s);
    if (x == 1)
    {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else if (x == 0)
    {
        printf("False\n");
    }
}

bool only_digits(string s);
{
    for (i= 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s [i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!isdigit(s [i]))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop in `only_digits` is pointless.  You will return from the function during the first iteration every time.  Reconsider the logic there.

Comment: what's `string`? There's no such type in C

Comment: @phuclv: [The Harvard cs50 library does `typedef char *string;`.](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/97bca133c0cb18bf0f20edc9afda4dcf07d75c0b/src/cs50.h#L51)  You wouldn't be the first person to think it's obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really close to being correct. There are a couple of things:

1. remove the semicolon from the definition of only_digits.

```
bool only_digits(string s);
{
```

should be:

```
bool only_digits(string s)
{
```

2. make the i in the loop an int.

```
for( i =
```

should be:

```
for( int i =
```

3. fix the logic in the loop so it returns false (aka 0) if any character is not a digit, else if it gets all the way through the loop return true.

```
bool
only_digits (string s)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen (s); i++)
    {
      if (!isdigit (s[i]))
    {
      return 0;
    }
    }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon(;) needs to be removed:

```
bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (i= 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and you can simply use `else` in place of `else if` because `if s[i]` is not
A digit, then it doesn't matter what it is we just need to return `false` or `0` in that condition

Answer (score 0):

> How do I take `argv[1]` from `main` so that I can use it in my function called `only_digits`?

In your `main`,  the expression `argv[1]` designates an object of type `string`.  You can do with it anything that you can do with any other `string`, including pass it as a function argument.  Your `only_digits()` function expects an argument of type `string`, so you don't need to do anything special to pass `argv[1]` to it.  This will work fine:

```
    x = only_digits(argv[1]);
```

You can also assign `argv[1]` to a variable of type `string`, and then pass the value of that variable, as the code you present does.  That's needlessly roundabout, but it will work fine, too.

However, if your function is intended to determine whether all the characters in the string that is passed to it are decimal digits, then it is buggy, as other answers describe in more detail.  Loop notwithstanding, it decides what value to return based only on the *first* character in its input string, because either one or the other conditional inside the loop must evaluate to true no matter what that character is, and the function returns either way.  It also fails to return anything at all in the event that an empty string is passed to it.

Note also that CS50 makes the unfortunate choice of using `string` as an alias for type `char *`.  This is perhaps easier to read, and it defers the need to talk about pointers, but it sets students up for confusion later on when they discover that `string`s seem to behave differently than objects of most other data types.

> It is also the first time I've used a bool function. I'm wondering if, in the `<cs50.h>` library, you can use strings and bools the way I used them here. Am I using them right?

There is nothing inherently wrong with the way you are using `string` and `bool`.  Probably the compiler would warn you if there were, or even outright reject the code.  Your program produces different results than you expect because it contains logic errors.

Answer (score 0):

You ask two questions.

First, there's no need for `string s`. `argv[]` is an array of pointers to strings, so you could pass the string of interest like so:

```
x = only_digits( argv[1] );
```

BUT, before using it, you must test that the user has supplied a string:

```
if( argc == 2 )
    x = only_digits( argv[1] );
```

Second, returning 1 for true or 0 for false, will work, but you should use the tokens that mean boolean results.

```
return true; // or return false;
```

Here's a version that moves the function ahead of its invocation. In this way, there's no need for a function prototype.

```
bool only_digits( string s )
{
    while( isdigit( *s ) )
        s++;

    // TRUE if reached end of string
    if( *s == '\0' )
        return true;
    return false;
}

void main( int argc, string argv[] )
{
    if( argc == 2 && argv[1][0] != '\0' && only_digits( argv[1] ) )
        printf( "True\n" );
    else
        printf( "False\n" );
}
```